# Is it possible to order (dplyr arrange?) a skim_df object by mean?

Tags: r, skimr

I am using the package `skimr` to summarize data that are all logicals, so naturally I would like to order the result by the mean from largest to smallest.

I have already attempted to pipe the skim function to `arrange` for dplyr but that didn't work.

We are simply using the `skim` function on a data frame that are all booleans/logicals.

Comment: Can you share an example of your data/code so that we can test out possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried that, and seems like everything works as intended. `skim_df` inherits from `data.frame`, I don't see why `dplyr` functions will not work on it.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(T,F), 50, replace = TRUE),
              b = c(rep(F,25), sample(c(T,F), 25, replace = TRUE)),
              c = c(rep(T,25), sample(c(T,F), 25, replace = TRUE)))

sdf <- skimr::skim(df) %>%
     dplyr::filter(stat == "mean") %>% dplyr::arrange(desc(value))

sdf
```

**Output**

```
variable type    stat  level value formatted
  <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>    
1 c        logical mean  .all   0.8  0.8      
2 a        logical mean  .all   0.5  0.5      
3 b        logical mean  .all   0.26 0.26
```

I don't know what your problem is. Carefully check your code for obvious errors.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't using the filter stage for `stat == mean` Thanks a bunch!

Comment: FYI this is going to change with the release of skimr v2 which is imminent.  It doesn't have the long structure although to_long would probably still work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for v2.  In v2 the skim object is no longer the long object. Here `select()` turns the skim object into a regular tibble (focus()) would have kept it as a skimr object).

```
skim(df) %>% dplyr::select(skim_variable, logical.mean) %>% 
             dplyr::arrange(desc(logical.mean)) 
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  skim_variable logical.mean
  <chr>                <dbl>
1 c                     0.7 
2 a                     0.6 
3 b                     0.34
```

Alternatively

```
skim(df) %>% skimr::focus(skim_variable, logical.mean) %>% 
             dplyr::arrange(desc(logical.mean)) %>% as.data.frame()

  skim_type skim_variable logical.mean
1   logical             c         0.70
2   logical             a         0.60
3   logical             b         0.34
```

leaves the two meta columns in place. The `as.data.frame()` is one way to keep the summary from printing but you can also tell it to print with the summary excluded.

```
skim(df) %>% skimr::focus(skim_variable, logical.mean) %>% 
             dplyr::arrange(desc(logical.mean)) %>% 
             print(include_summary = FALSE)

── Variable type: logical ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable  mean
1 c              0.7 
2 a              0.6 
3 b              0.34
```